# Dropping observations inside a loop is not working with mediate

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, regression

I've written a `for` loop around a mediate function from mediation package to test all outcome variable j with mediator i with treatment variable "treat". If I select the outcome and mediator by hand the function works and drops the unmatched observations with `dropobs = T` but within the for loop it fails to do so I get an error:

`Error in mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat = e$treat, mediator = e[, i],  :  number of observations do not match between mediator and outcome models`

The loop:

```
for (i in mediator)
{ for (j in outcome)
{ 
  model.Y <- lm(e[ ,j] ~ e$treat + e[, i], data=e)
  model.M <- lm(e[, i] ~ e$treat, data=e)

results <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat= "treat", mediator= i,
          boot=F, sims=1000, dropobs = T, control.value = "No", treat.value = "Yes")
}
}
```

I've tried adding the `data=e` and `e$` since that seemed to help with the handwritten function.

I would appreciate any handy tricks to try to get it to work?

Edit: Reproducible example

```
install.packages("mediation")
library(mediation)    
data(Cars93,package="MASS")

mediator <- c("Weight", "Width", "Length")
outcome <- c("Price", "EngineSize")
kolumns <- c("outcome", "mediator", "effect", "sig")


MED = data.frame (matrix(nrow = length(mediator)*length(outcome), ncol = length(kolumns)))
names (MED) = kolumns
MED$outcome = rep(outcome, each=length(mediator))
MED$mediator = rep(mediator, times=length(outcome))


for (i in mediator)
{ for (j in outcome)
{ 
  model.Y <- lm(Cars93[ ,j] ~ Cars93$Origin + Cars93[, i], data=Cars93)
  model.M <- lm(Cars93[, i] ~ Cars93$Origin, data=Cars93)

  results <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat= Cars93$Origin, mediator= Cars93[,i],
                     boot=F, sims=100, dropobs = T)

  MED[MED$outcome ==j & MED$mediator ==i, "effect"] = 
    summary(results)$d.avg
  MED[MED$outcome ==j & MED$mediator ==i, "sig"] = 
    summary(results)$d.avg.p

}
}
```

Comment: You may need to create a formula with the columns.  Possibly `lm(as.formula(paste(j, '~', treat, " + ", i)), data = e)` similarly for the second `lm` as well (assuming that 'i', 'j' are column names

Comment: I will try that however I can't get the the handwritten function to work anymore either so I'm wondering if it's a bug in the package/function

Comment: it could be.  Can't comment without a reproducible example

Comment: Hi @akrun I've added a reproducible example with Cars93 data